# XSLT convert XML to JSON

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am new with xslt and I am facing an issue when I try to convert a xml to Json.
The main problem is that I can not update the variables inside the loop. *So, I am to handle  with multiples .* 
Any thoughts? 
Thank you!

**input xml:**

```
<attributes>
 <name>uid</name>
 <values>user123</values>
 <name>mail</name>
 <values>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</values>
 <name>ismemberof</name>
 <values>cn=Partner xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx dc=com</values>
 <values>cn=Partner zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz dc=com</values>
 <values>ccn=Partner 444444444444444 dc=com</values>
 <values>cn=MANSFIELD MEDICAL,teste teste</values>
 <values>cn=Partner Portal - hthththththththt</values>
<name>dn</name>
<values>uid=user123,ou=people,dc=tttt,dc=com</values>
<name>telephoneNumber</name>
<name>objectClass</name>
<values>person</values>
<values>inetorgperson</values>
<values>dspswuser</values>
<values>top</values>
</attributes>
```

**My xslT code :**

```
<xsl:template match="/">    
<xsl:for-each select = "attributes/*">    
<xsl:if test = "(name(.) = 'name')"> 
<xsl:value-of select="concat(text(),':[&quot;')" />    
  </xsl:if>
 <xsl:if test = "(name(.) = 'values')">     
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(text(),'&quot;],')" />    
</xsl:if>    
</xsl:for-each>     
</xsl:template>
```

**Expected output:**

```
{
    "username": "bjensen",
       "realm": "/",
       "uid": [
           "bjensen"
       ],
       "mail": [
           "bjensen@example.com"
       ],
       "sn": [
           "bjensen"
       ],    
       "dn": [
           "uid=bjensen,ou=people,dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org"
       ],
       "objectclass": [
           "person",
           "sunIdentityServerLibertyPPService",
           "sunFederationManagerDataStore",
            "top"
       ],
       "universalid": [
           "id=bjensen,ou=user,dc=openam,dc=forgerock,dc=org"
       ]
}
```

Comment: Are you required to use some ancient XSLT 1 and do some XML to JSON conversion implemented on your own? In XSLT 3 (a W3C recommendation since last year and available in the open-source Saxon 9.8 HE for Java, .NET and C/C++) you have powerful grouping and you have support for JSON via the XPath 3.1 map and array data types and there is a specialized serialization method `json` and additionally some predefined functions like https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-xml-to-json.

Comment: It's very hard to see how your output relates to your input. None of the output data seems to bear any relationship to the input data. This makes it hard to see how to convert one to the other.

Comment: you are right Michael Kay. After I converted the XML input for a decent standard. My XSLT works properly.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear which input format you have and how you want to map it to JSON but part of the data you have presented looks like you could use `for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="name"` on the child elements of the `attributes` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="attributes">
      <xsl:map>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="name">
              <xsl:map-entry key="." select="array { data(tail(current-group())) }"/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:map>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This assumes an XSLT 3 processor like Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 or Altova XML 2017 or 2018 or 2019 and will for your input give a JSON result like

```json
 {
  "dn": [
    "uid=user123,ou=people,dc=tttt,dc=com"
   ],
  "telephoneNumber": [

   ],
  "uid": [
    "user123"
   ],
  "mail": [
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   ],
  "objectClass": [
    "person",
    "inetorgperson",
    "dspswuser",
    "top"
   ],
  "ismemberof": [
    "cn=Partner xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx dc=com",
    "cn=Partner zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz dc=com",
    "ccn=Partner 444444444444444 dc=com",
    "cn=MANSFIELD MEDICAL,teste teste",
    "cn=Partner Portal - hthththththththt"
   ]
 }
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBtX